Computing Chow groups of affine, simplicial toric varieties
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional affine, simplicial toric variety over $k$. There exists an $n$-dimensional simplicial cone $\sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $X=\operatorname{Spec}(k[{\sigma}^{\vee}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n])$.I am trying to compute all the Chow groups of $X$. I know that $X$ is the quotient $\mathbb{A}^n/G$, where $G$ is the finite abelian group $N/N’$.
Here $N$ is the lattice of one-parameter subgroups and $N’$ is the sublattice of $N$ generated by the minimal generators of the simplicial cone $\sigma$.
I am reading Edidin and Graham’s paper “Equivariant Intersection Theory” for this.
The paper mentions that equivariant Chow groups have all the formal properties of Chow groups. And proposition 8 in section 4 Intersection theory on quotients says that if an algebraic group $G$ acts with trivial stabilizer on an algebraic space $X$ and $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ is the principal bundle quotient, then $A_{i+g}^G(X)=A_i(Y)$, where $g$ is the dimension of $G$.
Since the projection map of a vector bundle induces isomorphisms on the equivariant chow groups, my question reduces to computing the equivariant Chow groups $A_i^G(\operatorname{Spec}(k))$. I would like to ask how to compute these groups.
